# Entity Framework Linq Entity convert to CustomModel

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have the following linq to entity:

```
  var dbShifts = DbContext.Set < SetupShift > ()
      .AsNoTracking()
      .Where(s => s.ShiftCode == shiftCode).ToList();
```

The Entity SetupShift has the following properties:

```
public class SetupShift
    {
        public int ShiftId { get; set; }
        public string ShiftCode { get; set; }
        public byte Day { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan InTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan OutTime { get; set; }
        public int WorkHours { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan LunchOut { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan LunchIn { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string CategoryType { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I need to wrap it to a custom model `ShiftModel`:

```
 public class ShiftModel
    {
        public int ShiftId { get; set; }
        public string ShiftCode { get; set; }
        public byte Day { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }
        public string InTime { get; set; }
        public string OutTime { get; set; }
        public int WorkHours { get; set; }
        public string LunchOut { get; set; }
        public string LunchIn { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string CategoryType { get; set; }
    }
```

The only difference between the **EF Entity model** and my `ShiftModel` is that the `TimeSpan` properties are `String` in the **Custom model**.

I would like to know if there is a fast way to generate my ShiftModel from my Entity data instead of looping every entity:

```
List<ShiftModel> shifts = new List<ShiftModel>();

foreach(var entity in SetupShift){
       ....
       newShiftModel = new ShiftModel();
       newShiftModel.InTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
       ....
       ....
       shifts.Add(newShiftModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var dbShifts = DbContext.Set < SetupShift > () .AsNoTracking() .Where(s => s.ShiftCode == shiftCode).Select(x => new ShiftModel() { 
 ShiftId = x.ShiftId, 
 ShiftCode = x.ShiftCode, 
Etc..... 
}).ToList();
```

Apologies for the poor formatting answering this from my phone.

Comment: That won't work because at some point I need to do: .ToString(@"hh\:mm"); and inside the Linq statement that will trough an error.

Comment: Check out this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1939418.aspx?Linq+To+Entities+Can+t+convert+DateTime+to+string+